# How to delete all the content in the file before input new content c++

Tags: c++

I facing a problem in my program, I would like to delete all the content and re-input it but my text file previous content will not remove. I would like to know how to solve it.

My Text file format :

jam:A7D579BA76398070EAE654C30FF153A4C273272A:9BB8F747A1C0DEA66C6FAF43391FEEAB:7F273F63581093D2:08102018:
kelly:7C222FB2927D828AF22F592134E8932480637C0D:06FE625E35A95669B866B914ABE818DE:7F273F63581093D2:08102018:

My Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <ctime>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
using namespace std;


string SHA_1(const string& input_data)
{
    string digest;
    SHA1 hash;

    StringSource s(input_data, true, new HashFilter(hash, new HexEncoder(new StringSink(digest))));

    return digest;
}

void outfile (string filename, string u, string p , string k, string iv, string d)
{

    ofstream outfile, outfile_2;
    outfile_2.open ("Account.txt", ios::out | ios::app);
    outfile_2 << u + ":" + p + ":" + ":" + k + ":" + iv + ":" + d + ":";
    outfile_2.close();
}
int main()
{

    ifstream infile_Account;
    infile_Account.open("Account.txt", ios::in);
    string UserAccount;

    string KEY_2;
    string IV_2;

    string Username = "kelly";
    string Password = "12345678";
    string Hashed_Password = SHA_1(Password);
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    if (!infile_Account)
    {
        cout << "File " << endl;
        return 0;
    }
    while(infile_Account >> UserAccount)
    {
        //cout << UserAccount << endl;
        i++;
    }
    infile_Account.close();
    string u, p , k , iv ,d;

    cout << i << endl;

    ifstream infile_Account_2;
    infile_Account_2.open("Account.txt", ios::in);
    ofstream outfile1;

    for (int j =0; j<i ; j++)
    {
        getline(infile_Account_2,u, ':');
        getline(infile_Account_2,p, ':');
        getline(infile_Account_2,k, ':');
        getline(infile_Account_2,iv, ':');
        getline(infile_Account_2,d, ':');

        /*cout << u << endl;
        cout << p << endl;
        cout << k << endl;
        cout << iv << endl;
        cout << d << endl;*/

        if (u == Username && p == Hashed_Password )
        {
            p = "78965478";
        }

        outfile("Account.txt",u,p,k,iv,d);
    }
}
```

The result of my files after executing the program:

```
kelly:7C222FB2927D828AF22F592134E8932480637C0D:06FE625E35A95669B866B914ABE818DE:7F273F63581093D2:08102018:
jam:A7D579BA76398070EAE654C30FF153A4C273272A:9BB8F747A1C0DEA66C6FAF43391FEEAB:7F273F63581093D2:08102018:
kelly:78965478:06FE625E35A95669B866B914ABE818DE:7F273F63581093D2:08102018:
jam:A7D579BA76398070EAE654C30FF153A4C273272A:9BB8F747A1C0DEA66C6FAF43391FEEAB:7F273F63581093D2:08102018:
```

Comment: Don't open the output file in append mode? [This `filebuf::open` reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_filebuf/open) should hopefully help you understand the different open-modes better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are opening your file with `ios::app`. So you are asking to append data. Juste remove the flag... And read the documentation.

Comment: I had tried before removing the ios::app but it will output the last line to the file.

Comment: That's because you are opening and closing the file in a loop, which is very bad. Open the file once and write to it. Once again, read the documentation.